# Upload text file without extension

Tags: 7, files

I am working in a project where I have to upload files thru a Drupal site. I am having an issue since the files I am trying to upload have not extension. The files are text files, but without the .txt at the end and to be honest I don't mind if Drupal add .txt after the file name.

How do I define a file validator for files without extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be sure you are uploading text files, just without extension, you need two steps:

1. Omit extension validation. You don't want to simply only allow empty extension, as you may have a dot inside legitimate filename. Code would be like:

   ```
   $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array());
   ```

   Hint: It's easier to use `#upload_validators` on [`managed_file`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#managed_file) element when you are using Drupal 7, than to use `file` element and `file_save_upload`.
2. Test if what you got is really a text file. Linux-based hosts are pretty good at it. Code needed in your validator will look like:

   ```
   $file_handler = file_load($file_name);
   if(is_null($file_handler) or empty($file_handler->filemime)) {
     // output message like 'Could not validate file type. Please contact site administraotrs.'
   }
   $mimetype = $file_handler->filemime;
   if($mimetype != 'text/plain') {
     // set error
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that leaving the extension with an space instead of empty work, but I wonder how secure it this solution. In my case I remove the file a second after I upload it as I am only interested on its content.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
$validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array(' '));
$file = file_save_upload($i, $validators);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Allow All File Extensions](https://drupal.org/project/allow_all_file_extensions) you can try this module and I'm not tested it.

> lengthens the allowed file extensions box from 128 characters to
>   2048, allowing you to specify a larger number of extensions.